# (err)ERR Unsupported CONFIG parameter: module-add

Tags: redis

When I try to add a module to redis, i get the error : 
`(err) ERR Unsupported CONFIG parameter: module-add`

I've installed dynamic redis in the following manner :-

```
$mkdir -p ~/repos
$cd ~/repos
$git clone https://github.com/mattsta/redis
$cd redis
$git checkout dynamic-redis-unstable
$cd ..
$git clone https://github.com/mattsta/krmt
$cd krmt
$make -j
$redis-cli config set module-add `pwd`/geo.so
```

Without any error through the process, right uptil when I attempted a module-add

Any idea why?

Comment: You should follow the complete building instructions,  https://github.com/mattsta/krmt#building You've missed some steps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to re-install redis using `dynamic-redis-unstable` branch.